# Choose all possible 3 points from a 2D array

Tags: algorithm

I am just out of ideas for my school project associated with algorithms and data structures. I need to iterate through a 2D array of known `height` and `width` so that I choose all possible positions of `n` points.

For example for data `height = 2, width = 2, n = 1` output would be:

```
1) x=0, y=0
2) x=1, y=0
3) x=0, y=1
4) x=1, y=1
```

For data `height = 2, width = 2, n = 2` there would be 16 points. I hope you get what I mean

It is quite simple for 2x2 with 1 point but the thing is that algorithm should be universal. I'm just stuck. Is there any fast way to achieve this?

Comment: What's `n` here?

Comment: Number of points to choose

Comment: I've found an algorithm for that - it is `hungarian method`